# How to remove CR LF end of line in Perl

Tags: perl

I need to remove and of the line which looks like CR LF.

Coding - Windows-1250
Windows 7 EN

I have been trying to chomp, chomp, change \R to nothing change \r\n etc but nothing works...

Thank you in advance

```
use strict;
$/ = "\r\n";
open FILE , "<", "file.txt" or die $!;
while (<FILE>) {
    my @line = split /,/ , $_;

    foreach my $l (@line) {
        print $l;
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881779/neatest-way-to-remove-linebreaks-in-perl

Comment: You should write *how* you have been trying things. Apparently you are not doing something right. Show the code of what you have tried, including input and output.

Comment: I have added $/ but it blocks my script. I updated my post

Comment: I can't hear `chomp`ing. (In your code...)

Comment: Note that you should normally use `local $/ = "\r\n";` in as limited a scope as feasible, rather than resetting it globally for everything.  In this sample code, it is not critical, but as a good Perl coding practice, avoid modifying most of the global special variables without using `local`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, you don't even try to change the CRLF to LF. You just print back out what you got.

On a Windows system, Perl adds the `:crlf` layer to your file handles. That means that CRLF gets changed to LF on read, and LF gets changed to CRLF on write.

That last bit is the problem. By default, Perl assumes you're create a text file, but what you're creating doesn't match the definition of a text file on Windows. As such, you need to switch your output to `binmode`.

Solution that only works on a Windows system:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

binmode(STDOUT);

open(my $fh, '<', 'file.txt') or die $!;
print while <$fh>;
```

Or if you want it to work on any system,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

binmode(STDOUT);

open(my $fh, '<', 'file.txt') or die $!;
while (<$fh>) { 
   s/\r?\n\z//;
   print "$_\n";
}
```

Without binmode on the input,

- You'll get CRLF for CRLF on a non-Windows system.
- You'll get LF for CRLF on a Windows system.
- You'll get LF for LF on all systems.

`s/\r?\n\z//` handles all of those.

Comment: it is working, but under linux i see \z as unrecognized escape.

Comment: @Znik, I don't know what you mean by "under linux". This question was about Perl, and `\z` matches end of string in Perl (regardless of OS). `$` matches end of string in some other languages with Perl-like regex syntax, but `$` doesn't match (just) end of string in Perl.

Comment: I tryed test this code under some linux. perl is not independed on OS, and must respect OS behavior. on some linux distributions /z is working, on some not. It is usually repaired on frech perl version, but on older installed on older linuxes distro it is not working.

Comment: @Znik, It's `\z`, not `/z`. And you are quite wrong. Perl's regex engine is completely independent of OS. Aussi, c'est indépendant de la langue de la locale. Furthermore, `\z` has existed since at least 5.6 (20 years and 13 versions ago), when I first started using Perl. I suspect it's been in Perl since far longer, though. I don't know what you tried (cause you didn't show anything), but what you are saying is just plain untrue. Are you actually using `perl`, or something that has support for "Perl-like" regex? The latter doesn't mean `perl` is used, and this questions was tagged `perl`.

Answer (score 2):

if you are on Unix like command line, on the shell prompt the following with do the trick:

`perl -pe 's/^M//g' file.txt # ^M mean control-M, press control-v control-M, the CRLF character`

`perl -pe 's#\r\n$#\n#g' file.txt`

Comment: thanks for posting this, can you explain what the `#` character is doing here? I am not very familiar with Perl, only using it for this use-case

Comment: @user5359531: In the first command, the `#` starts a shell comment.  In the second command, `#` is used as an alternative separator in the `s///` operator.  There's no obvious reason for using it, but it does no harm (except to confuse the innocent).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on a Mac (Mac OS X 10.7.5, Perl 5.16.2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>)
{
    print "1: [$_]\n";
    {
        local $/ = "\r\n";
        chomp;
    }
    print "2: [$_]\n";
}
```

Sample output:

```
$  odx x3.txt
0x0000: 6F 6E 69 6F 6E 0D 0A 73 74 61 74 65 0D 0A 6D 69   onion..state..mi
0x0010: 73 68 6D 61 73 68 0D 0A                           shmash..
0x0018:
$ perl x3.pl < x3.txt | vis -c
1: [onion^M
]
2: [onion]
1: [state^M
]
2: [state]
1: [mishmash^M
]
2: [mishmash]
$
```

The `odx` program gives me a hex dump of the data file; you can see that there are 0D 0A (CRLF) line endings.  The `vis -c` program shows control characters (other than newline and tab) as `^M` (for example).  You can see that the raw input includes the `^M` (lines starting `1:`) but the `chomp`'d lines are missing both the newline and the carriage return.

The only issue will be whether the input on Windows is a text file or a binary file.  If it is a text file, the I/O system should do the CRLF mapping automatically.  If it is a binary file, it won't.  (Unix doesn't have a meaningful distinction between text and binary files.)  On Windows, you may need to investigate [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html), as discussed on the [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) page.

Comment: @ikegami: would you like to elaborate on why it won't work on Windows, other than Windows being different from Unix?

Comment: `$_` doesn't contains CRLF, so the `chomp` won't do anything. `print "\n";` to a text files puts CR LF in the text file. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a one-liner in Perl... Try the following under Linux:

```
perl -0pe 's/[\r\n]//g' < file.txt
sleep 1
```

and the following under Windows:

```
perl.exe -0pe "s/\015\012|\015|\012//g" < file.txt
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
```

Comment: Code seems OK, but why the *sleeping*?

Comment: look @ the original "sleep(1);" LOL

Comment: No good. Both snippets merge all lines. Not what he asked for. Did you try it yourself? (btw, Why do you switch to paragraph mode using `-0`?!?!)

Answer (score 0):

I think \s* should work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open FILE , "<", "file.txt" or die $!;

while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {

    $line =~ s{ \s* \z}{}xms;  # trim trailing whitespace of any kind

    my @columns = split /,/ , $line;

    for my $column (@columns) {

        print "$column ";
    }
    sleep(1);

    print "\n";
}
```